# Why this column not accept duplicate id ? nestjs, TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

i have two entities `student` and `department`. the relation is `one to many` and `many to one`... means many student have one department. but i try to insert student data with `department id`.  if department id is already exist so the `departmentId` automatically set `null`, why?
**Database **
***current :***

```
id  |  name |  age  | departmentId
1   | xyz      |   35   |   null
1   |  asdf    |   33   |   1
```

**Expected :**

```
id  |  name |  age  | departmentId
1   | xyz      |   35   |   1
1   |  asdf    |   33   |   1      // means repeat id accept
```

**student.entity.ts**

```
@ManyToOne(()=>Department, (department)=>department.students)
department : Department
```

**department.entity.ts**

```
@OneToMany(()=>Student, (student)=>student.department)
students: Student[]
```

**student.service.ts**

```
async createStudent(departmentId: number, studentModel: studentDto) {
    let studentInfo = {
      name: studentModel.name,
      age: studentModel.age,
    };
    const departmentInfo = await this.departmentRepo.findOneBy({
      id: departmentId,
    });
    const student = this.studentRepo.create({ ...studentInfo });
    const studentRes = await this.studentRepo.save(student);
    const department = this.departmentRepo.create({ ...departmentInfo });
    department.students = [studentRes];
    const departmentRes = await this.departmentRepo.save(department);
    return departmentRes
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. We would like to add a new student to a department, so there is **no** need to create a new department entity and link it with student and save it.
2. The student that you are creating doesn't have any departmentId is set, so it's expected typeorm to interpret this as null departmentId since it's null.

I'd first define cascade for student,
This code should work but I hope you understand the cause of the issue.

```
async createStudent(departmentId: number, studentModel: studentDto) {
    const studentInfo = {
      name: studentModel.name,
      age: studentModel.age,
    };
    //maybe check if departmentId is valid
    studentInfo.departmentId = departmentId;
    
    const student = this.studentRepo.create({ ...studentInfo });
    const studentRes = await this.studentRepo.save(student);
    const department = await this.departmentRepo.findBy({id: departmentId});
    return department;
  }
```

Comment: but departmentId is not a part of `student` entity, it only a relation ( ManyToOne ).. `department` is a unique entity